# File-upload error using Cordova FileTransfer to NodeJS

Tags: node.js, cordova, file-transfer

I'm currently working on a Phonegap app, and I would like users to be able to upload any file to my NodeJS server.

I've looking all around the web but I just can't get anything to work...

Here is the code I'm using for the Phonegap controller:

```
$scope.open = function()
{
        navigator.camera.getPicture(upload, 
        function(message) 
        {
            alert('get picture failed');
        }, 
        { 
            quality: 50,
            destinationType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
            mediaType: navigator.camera.MediaType.ALLMEDIA  
        });

    }

    var win = function (r) {
        $scope.log = "Code = " + r.responseCode;
        $scope.log2 = "Response = " + r.response;
        $scope.log3 = "Sent = " + r.bytesSent;
        $scope.$digest();  

    }

    var fail = function (error) {
        $scope.log = "An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code;
        $scope.log2 = "upload error source " + error.source;
        $scope.log3 = "upload error target " + error.target;
        $scope.$digest();  
    }

    function upload(fileURI)
    {
        $scope.log = fileURI;
        $scope.$digest();  

        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey = "file";
        options.fileName = fileURI.substr(fileURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        options.mimeType = "text/plain";
        options.chunkedMode = false;

        var params = {};
        params.value1 = "test";
        params.value2 = "param";
        options.params = params;

        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.upload(fileURI, "http://192.168.192.111:2999/upload", win, fail, options);
    }.
```

Here is the current code for the NodeJS server, have tried a lot of different things, all without success:

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http').Server(express);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var fs = require('fs');

var multer = require('multer');
var app = new express();


app.post('/upload', multer({dest: './uploads/'}).single('upl'), function(req, res)
{
  console.log(req.body);
  console.log(req.file);
})


http.listen(2999, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:2999');
});
```

In the app I used to get errors that FileUploadOptions etc weren't defined, but I fixed that by adding them to the cordova project.
Furthermore, I use ionic 1, if that helps anyone out.

I do keep constantly getting the error code 1 (upload error source), even though I selected a real file and I saw that the link was correct (something like /storage/0/emulated/Downloads on my Android device).

Also, sometimes it gives me error 3 as well (upload target source), some sort of server not found issue I think.

Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong and how would I be able to fix it? Is there a handier way, since I eventually want to link this to a MySQL database.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well found my answer (a while ago, this is for people stumbling across this post).

You can first try whether your JS works by changing the server to https://posttestserver.com/post.php. If you see an upload appearing there, there's a problem with the server.

The problem with me was that I didn't let Apache through the firewall at all, so uploads from anything besides my PC would fail...

Answer (score 0):

```
var express=require('express');
var bodyParser=require('body-parser');
var formidable = require('formidable');
var util = require('util');
var app=express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
var path=require('path');
var mysql =require('mysql');
var fs=require('fs');

app.use('/public',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password : '',
        port : 3306, //port mysql
        database:'xxxxx'
});
app.post('/data', function(req, res) {

 // create an incoming form object
  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm(),
        files = [],
        fields = [];
  // specify that we want to allow the user to upload multiple files in a single request
  form.multiples = true;

  // store all uploads in the /uploads directory
  form.uploadDir = path.join(__dirname, '/public/images/uploads');
  // every time a file has been uploaded successfully,
  // rename it to it's orignal name
  form.on('file', function(field, file) {
    if (path.extname(file.name)=='') {
        extension='.jpg';
    }
    else{
      extension=path.extname(file.name);
    }
    var oldpath = file.path;
    form.uploadDir = path.basename(file.name,extension).concat((Math.random()* 100),extension);               
    var newpath = './public/images/uploads/'+ path.basename(file.name,extension).concat((Math.random()* 100),extension);

    //fs.rename(file.path, path.join(form.uploadDir, file.name));
    fs.rename(oldpath, newpath);
  });
  form.on('field', function(field, value) {
      fields[field] = value;   
  });

  // log any errors that occur
  form.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('An error has occured: \n' + err);
  });

  // once all the files have been uploaded, send a response to the client

//Call back at the end of the form.
form.on('end', function () {

    res.writeHead(200, {
        'content-type': 'text/plain'
    });
    res.write('received the data:\n\n');


   // console.log(fields.name+'-'+fields.nickname);
    var values={
          name:fields.name,
          nickname:fields.nickname,
          email:fields.email,
          password:fields.password,
          dob:fields.dob,
          gender:fields.gender,
          phoneno:fields.phone
      };

    connection.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', values, function(err,req,res){
                        if(err){
                          console.log('Connection result error '+err);

                        }
                            else{
                        console.log('Success');     

                            }
                });

               res.end();  


});
  // parse the incoming request containing the form data
  form.parse(req);
});

//app.use(app.router);
app.listen(5000);
```

Comment: Its a complete code  form fields from ajax+jquery to nodejs and save into mysql DB

Comment: Code only answers should generally be avoided.  Part of the reason why I like SO is that you should be able to understand the solution and not just learn how to cut & paste code.